# Robotium: Launch app from the background

Tags: android, robotium

In my Robotium test, I send the app to the background by sending the Home Key code.

```
solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
```

How do I launch the app into the background?

There is the launchActivity method but I don't want to specify the activity. Just move the app to the foreground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly with robotium alone I do not believe this is possible. As soon as the app you are testing loses focus you are no longer able to instrument against it and therefore robotium can no longetr launch your application.

If you want to test things like this you can either use the instrumentation methods such as callActivityOnResume etc, use a differnt test framework (the UI automator one by google does not have the same restriction) or you can find a way to use adb to re laucnh your app and allow instrumentation to occur. You might also be able to create a service that would re laucnh your app too. All but the first and second will involve a fair bit of work sadly.